# Getting NPE (Edited)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, runtime

I'm still getting NPE but now it's from my onCreate(). When I remove the buttons everything works fine though.

Here are the XML(each table rows are from separate XMLs):

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/doneP1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Done" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resetP1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reset" />

    </TableRow>

<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/doneP2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Done" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/resetP2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reset" />

        </TableRow>
```

Here's the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tictactoegame);

        /*doneP1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.doneP1);
        doneP2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.doneP2);
        resetP1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.resetP1);
        resetP2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.resetP2);

        checkTurn(); //starts the game

        //buttons
        doneP1.setOnClickListener(this);
        doneP2.setOnClickListener(this);
        resetP1.setOnClickListener(this);
        resetP2.setOnClickListener(this);*/ //commented out 
    }
```

and outside the onCreate

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
       switch(v.getId()) {
       case R.id.doneP1:
            checkTurn();
           break;
       case R.id.doneP2:
           checkTurn();
           break;
       case R.id.resetP1:
           break;
       case R.id.resetP2:
           break;
       }
}
```

here is the checkturn

```
public void checkTurn()
    {
        if(turn == 1)
        {
            changeLayout(turn);
            turn = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            changeLayout(turn);
            turn = 1;
        }
    }
```

here is the changelayout(EDIT: new changeLayout, I just reinitialized each buttons inside the method but still no effect, am I doing it right?)

```
public void changeLayout(int turn)
{
    FragmentManager fm       = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment        fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    FragmentTransaction ft;

    if(turn == 1) //if its player 1's turn
    {  
        doneP1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.doneP1);
        resetP1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.resetP1);
        doneP1.setOnClickListener(this);
        resetP1.setOnClickListener(this);
        if(fragment == null) //checks wether the current framelayout contains a fragment or not
        {   
            ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, new PlayerTurn1());
            ft.commit(); 
            //setPlayer1();
        }
        else
        {
            ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PlayerTurn1());
            ft.commit();

        }
    }
    else
    {   
        doneP2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.doneP2); 
        resetP2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.resetP2);  
        doneP2.setOnClickListener(this);
        resetP2.setOnClickListener(this);
        if(fragment == null)
        {
            ft = fm.beginTransaction();;
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, new PlayerTurn2());
            ft.commit(); 
            //setPlayer2();
        }
        else
        {
            ft = fm.beginTransaction();;
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PlayerTurn2());
            ft.commit(); 
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the logcat

> 03-24 07:51:55.954: E/AndroidRuntime(5092): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-24 07:51:55.954:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(5092): at
>   As2.packageTK.TicTacToeGame.onCreate(TicTacToeGame.java:88)

line 88 is:

```
doneP1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I've been working on this for about 4 hours now and I still can't fix a simple problem. My head is drooling and I'm really tired, I want to fix this before I go to sleep so I'll appreciate a fast response. I cleaned and rebuilt my problem... nothing. Everything seems fine but no... NPE always has to bust in.

Comment: plz also add checkTurn(); code with question

Comment: I added them. Im pretty sure the code is right but every time i remove the buttons' code it works -.-

Comment: @user2203939 Can you just double-check that you've saved the layout file, cleaned, and rebuilt the project and are still getting the error?

Comment: @Tushar
Yup, just cleaned and rebuilt yet nothing works..

Comment: Is the tableview inside the fragment_container, by any chance?

Comment: @Tushar
Sorry, not sure if I understand your question right

Comment: Can you post all your relevant layout files? Just testing a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a NPE on

```
doneP1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

that means that doneP1 is null. Have you checked by just printing/loggin doneP1, doneP2, resetP1 and resetP2 (before line 88 of course). For instance:

```
Log.d(TAG, "doneP1 = "+doneP1);
Log.d(TAG, "doneP2 = "+doneP2);
...
```

My guess is that all those components are null. That means that you're probably loading the wrong layout. Or maybe you load the correct one from the beginning but you change it out for something else in

```
public void changeLayout(int turn)
```

**EDIT:**

Your TableRows are in different layouts?

```
"Here are the XML(each table rows are from separate XMLs):"
```

Then of course the P1 components will be null when you load the P2 layout, and vice versa.

**EDIT2:**

Load your references in changeLayout. Since you only have two buttons on screen at the same time (reset and done) you would actually only need two references (i.e. you dont need both donep1 and donep2). And then in your change layout you change the reference to the correct button. So you need logic of whose turn it was in onClick of the buttons.

Comment: I havn't check the loggin yet but yes the tablerows are in different layout. They have to be since they're going to be put inside fragments. Each layout represents a player and each player has 2 buttons...
I don't see how all those components can be null I mean I'm not changing them as far as I'm seeing.
I'll check the logging and print it out

Comment: If you have loaded Player1's layout; then the components of Player2 will be null, right?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that every time I the changeLayout() method is called, fragment player1 is replaced by fragment player2 so basically I lose the ID reference to each buttons in both fragments. I updated what I tried to do in order to fix it but still no good.

Comment: So why do you need to load the references before you know whose turn it is? See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

As it look you are getting those view in `onCreate`:

```
  doneP1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.doneP1);
    doneP2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.doneP2);
    resetP1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.resetP1);
    resetP2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.resetP2);
```

but after you changed to turn and changed the layout in your:

```
public void checkTurn()
{
    if(turn == 1)
    {
        changeLayout(turn);
        turn = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        changeLayout(turn);
        turn = 1;
    }
}
```

and running this:

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new PlayerTurn1());
```

you are basically losing the reference to those views. because there are not existing anymore. they were replaced by the views of the other fragment.

**EDIT:**

An alternatice would be to set the `onClick` property in the layout file:

set the `"android:onClick="onDoneButtonOnClick"`

and in your activity create the method:

```
public void onDoneButtonOnClick (View v)
{
      // do here what every you want with this button.
}
```

In this case you would have to remove the implementation of `onClickListener` from your activity.

Comment: I think you're making sense. So it means I have to intialize them in while I'm recreating/replacing the view of the fragments?

Comment: So basically after you have replaced the layout you have to run again the findByViewId method again 4 time for your 4 views in order to reference the new views in the newly replaced fragment layout.

Comment: So its whenever the changeLayout is called, I need to reinitialize the button. It makes sense I'll try it out.
EDIT: just tested and it doesn't work. I might be doing something wrong though but is there a simplified way to do it instead of reintializing everytime?